# No linebreak with \refKey (tcolorbox documentation library)

Tags: line-breaking, tcolorbox, documentation

I currently try to document a LaTeX-package with several keys.
When I use the internal tools of the tcolorbox documentation library, I get some ugly results.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{documentation}

\begin{document}
\begin{docKey}[my/very/long/keypath]{myKey}{=\marg{value}}{}
    This is a very very very (very) very long description of the \refKey{/my/very/long/keypath/myKey}
\end{docKey}
\end{document}
```

This leads to
[image]
which can definitely be improved.

Is there a way to only get the last part (the key itself) when referencing the key?
Are there other ways to break the reference at line endings?

---

After some searching through the documentation, I found this part, which should be relevant for my question (lines 808 ff.):

```
\NewDocumentCommand\tcb@ref@doc{msm}{%
  \hyperref[#1:#3]{\texttt{\ref*{#1:#3}}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#2}{}{%
    \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{#1:#3}=\thepage\relax%
    \else%
      \textsuperscript{\ding{213}\,\kvtcb@text@pageshort\,\pageref*{#1:#3}}%
    \fi}}%
}

\def\refCom{\tcb@ref@doc{com}}
\def\refEnv{\tcb@ref@doc{env}}
\def\refKey{\tcb@ref@doc{key}}
```

What I probably need is a replacement for the `\ref*{#1:#3}` which extracts the last element of a `/`-separated list from the reference. But unfortunately I don't know, how I could achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the answer of @Marijn, I was able to make the changes in the current version of `tcolorbox` and want to share them here:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_gset:Npn \__tcobox_doc_head_key:
    {
        \__tcobox_print_key:
        \__tcobox_index_key:
        \tl_if_empty:NTF \kvtcb@doc@keypath
        {
            \seq_if_in:NVF \g__tcobox_label_seq \kvtcb@doc@label
            {
                \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\kvtcb@doc@name}
                \label{key:\kvtcb@doc@label}
                \seq_gput_left:NV \g__tcobox_label_seq \kvtcb@doc@label
            }
        }
        {
            \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {/\kvtcb@doc@keypath/\kvtcb@doc@label}
            \seq_if_in:NVF \g__tcobox_label_seq \l_tmpa_tl
            {
                % define the short ref
                \protected@edef\@currentlabel{/\kvtcb@doc@name}
                \label{key:/\kvtcb@doc@keypath/\kvtcb@doc@label}
                % define the long one
                \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\slash\kvtcb@doc@keypath\slash\kvtcb@doc@name}
                \label{key:*/\kvtcb@doc@keypath/\kvtcb@doc@label}
                \seq_gput_left:NV \g__tcobox_label_seq \l_tmpa_tl
            }
        }
        {\ttfamily\kvtcb@doc@parameter}
        \tcb@doc@do@description
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

This implements the long and short reference label as well as the line breaking functionality.

Answer (score 1):

For the question to get only the last part you can renew the `docKey` environment to add another label to the definition that prints only the key itself and not the path. In the MWE below the label is defined as `*/#1/\kvtcb@doc@label`, so you can reference it by prefixing the key with `*`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{documentation}

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{docKey}{ O{} +O{} m m +m }{\tcbset{doc label={#3},#2,doc description={#5}}%
  \begin{tcb@manual@entry}%
  \begin{tcb@doc@head}{doc@head@key}%
  \ifblank{#1}{%
    \tcb@Print@Key{#3}\tcb@index@Key{#3}\protected@edef\@currentlabel{#3}\label{key:\kvtcb@doc@label}{\ttfamily #4}%
  }{%
    \tcb@Print@Key{/#1/#3}%
    \tcb@index@KeyPath{#1}{#3}\protected@edef\@currentlabel{/#1/#3}\label{key:/#1/\kvtcb@doc@label}%
    % ADDED LABEL DEFINITION HERE
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{/#3}\label{key:*/#1/\kvtcb@doc@label}%
    {\ttfamily #4}%
  }%
  \tcb@doc@do@description%
  \end{tcb@doc@head}\nobreak\tcbset{before upper=}\kvtcb@doc@body@key@before\ignorespaces}%
  {\ifvmode\else\unskip\fi\kvtcb@doc@body@key@after\end{tcb@manual@entry}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{docKey}[my/very/long/keypath]{myKey}{=\marg{value}}{}
    This is a very very very (very) very long description of the \refKey{/my/very/long/keypath/myKey}
    This is a very very very (very) very long description of the \refKey{*/my/very/long/keypath/myKey}
\end{docKey}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that this code was tested using `tcolorbox` v4.22. The most recent version (currently 4.42) has had a major rewrite for which the code in this answer does not work out of the box.

For breaking the long keys you can change the environment definition to use `\slash` instead of a literal `/`, which will allow line breaking on the slashes. Because this is a command (which is not allowed in labels) you should define the printed text (with the `\slash` commands) and the label text (with the literal `/`) separately using the `doc label` key from `tcolorbox`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{documentation}

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{docKey}{ O{} +O{} m m +m }{\tcbset{doc label={#3},#2,doc description={#5}}%
  \begin{tcb@manual@entry}%
  \begin{tcb@doc@head}{doc@head@key}%
  \ifblank{#1}{%
    \tcb@Print@Key{#3}\tcb@index@Key{#3}\protected@edef\@currentlabel{#3}\label{key:\kvtcb@doc@label}{\ttfamily #4}%
  }{%
    \tcb@Print@Key{/#1/#3}%
    \tcb@index@KeyPath{#1}{#3}\protected@edef\@currentlabel{\slash#1\slash#3}\label{key:\kvtcb@doc@label}%
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{/#3}\label{key:*\kvtcb@doc@label}%
    {\ttfamily #4}%
  }%
  \tcb@doc@do@description%
  \end{tcb@doc@head}\nobreak\tcbset{before upper=}\kvtcb@doc@body@key@before\ignorespaces}%
  {\ifvmode\else\unskip\fi\kvtcb@doc@body@key@after\end{tcb@manual@entry}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{docKey}[my\slash very\slash long\slash keypath][doc label=/my/very/long/keypath/myKey]{myKey}{=\marg{value}}{}
    This is a very very very (very) very long description of the \refKey{/my/very/long/keypath/myKey}
    
    This is a very very very (very) very long description of the \refKey{*/my/very/long/keypath/myKey}
\end{docKey}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. As it turns out, the current version of tcolorbox has different definitions. But with your answer I was able to spot the relevant parts in the source and could change it. Therefore I will accept your answer and add the new (expl3-code modifications) in a separate answer.

Comment: @Wulle I'm happy to hear that my answer was helpful to find the actual solution. I think that you should accept your own answer instead (self-answers can be accepted after 48 hours I think) because it is actually more useful than mine as it targets the latest version of `tcolorbox`.